# Viewing attachments renders rubbish

Tags: attachment, pdf

We attached a number of PDFs to various Accounts under 'Notes and Attachments'. **Some users** when they click on the attachment a new window pops up and they see gibberish on the screen like. The browser is Chrome.

%PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ 4 0 obj <> /Length 77929 >> stream Z€ °ª4¤:M†ÐèÌ– £kPÑµ¨³MS^€Ì4˜ôa¦ÀÚÐ@tIh :6µôôZ€‰-FýD–€£~€£kPÑ¿@Ñ% €èÚÔZII2+è :$´ôôZ€�ú�ú�­@FýFÖ ¢K@Ñ¿@Ñµ¨€èß €èß €èÚÔ@toÐ@toÐ@tmj :7è :7è :6µôZ€�ú�­@FýFÖ £~€£kPÑµ¨€èß €èÚÔ@tmj :7è :6µôQ4½”MÃ%¨€èß €èß €èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :7è :6µZ€�ú�ú�­@FýFýD–€£kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èß €èÚÔ@tmj :7è :6µôôZ€�ú�­@FýFýFÖ £~€£~€£~€£~€£kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èß €èÚÔ@tmj :7è :6µôôZ€�ú�­@FÖ £~€£kPÑµ¨€èß €èÚÔ@toÐ@toÐ@tmj :7è :6µôZ€�ú�ú�­@FýFýFÖ £kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èÚÔ@tmj :7è :6µôZ€�ú�­@FÖ £~€Û3ÚƒkPÑµ¨€èß €èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :7è :6µôZ€�ú�­@FýFÖ £~€£kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èß €èß €èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :7è :7è :6µôZ€�ú�­@FýFýFÖ £~€£kPÑµ¨€èÚÔ@tmj :7è :6µZ€�ú�­@FýFÖ £~€£kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èß €èß €èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :6µôZ€�­@FýFÖ £~€£kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :6µôZ€�­@FÖ £~€£kPÑµ¨€èß €èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj&Ëx Š­@Ùo1_@Ñµ¨€èß €èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :6µô0·PÑµ¨€èß ´†$ÑPiI¢ mRM}FÖ £kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :6µZ€�ú�­@FýFÖ £~€£~€£kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èß €èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :7è :6µôZ€�­@FýFÖ £kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :7è :6µôZ€�ú�­@FýFÖ £kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èÚÔ@tIh :7è :$´Z€�ú�­@FýFÖ £~€£kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :6µZ€�­@FýFÖ £kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :6µôZ€�ú�­@FýFÖ £kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èß €èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :7è :6µôZ€ ü€Y_ €èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :7è :6µZ€�­@FÖ £~€£kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj :7è :6µôZ€�ú�­@FÖ £~€£kPÑµ¨€èß €èÚÔ@toÐ@toÐ@tmj :7è :6µZ€�ú�­@FýFÖ £kPÑ¿@Ñµ¨€èÚÔ@toÐ@tmj "_µ�mÍÛ…-@[ö!‹5(w­\B5Õ=‚Q¾fe¤:Ñn°‚f¤&•u ŠºšÔX$hÁ]`ë6õ;18,MNaD¨k©z �ib «xKôt„ ¡5u?vcV5Âý…7:y,'¼Ém‡ ÁYsÔÿö|¸ZÔXS©O%‚ªÜÙ-°àá¨.zŸô`Ošá^€ÂœâX*­Í’Û!†Àà\¹è>é?k…-@…8ÿÄ°U[›%¶E£�}ÙºÙŠ’á^€Â›§Ì– «sd¶Ðõaê%�eVí:ÙŠ’áKPaLõ¡Òd¡»Öæûæs ŽTã©êò·�f9ðh>$Pëf*K…-@…CÔx'!ø#…àžÜì:zfçefça:qyŽ;˜M^¦8Üî³à�NDŽÙû“ÀUà¾€Â ôéÛ€^uŸVàQÎ.u¹»|à+<;}[Ë.úÑÔp.yc°õ�+t­×tk‚­@‚Búß¾¹ã·á#÷[÷�î1ë±ãë»yõÌ7Sçjï³çŽñì©c¯©.è,Œïž\ùå:Þ?s½Öð±ýÎw<|íÛË>çë±Ñýw»i/±ýÎ¨ Ñ®è,,—¼xþÊu¼Rœœ?¿°ç}—»ºË–uºS¬ÚG—?¹ëº5ÁV ÂÈ¾ÿëŸÖçgÏß¹Õ»C£ßu:«î_c@8n£·Ju±ëXÌYýôýaº’á^€ÂQsÐñýnqôêUºïº¥«æƒÂ¤¡ÔñÒ�Pw¾½ŽˆÆÝà¾€ÂYô@ú�nuç7:·]÷Sª½øœ/Jêž:S¢©�p8|N£\j,:PñýnwÐþ�J·]÷Sª½ãºcÉ[Õã›�xC�„êK…z YS²çõ¹Øòúu*ÝwÝMë{ÊÙÊåoWŽ”èz³ª:š!Jmp¥¨°¥"ËÝžS­ÎËÓs«ußu7E—ÙcµîÝ0Þ�œÜètîµ«‘Š¿k…z R,¾ëŸÖç[ëé¹Õºïº¥NïwuÖçii{£úÜû€­zÝ)æ/—Z€

[image]

Comment: Do you have control over the MIME type that the server responds with for the PDF? Looks like the MIME type might be text, when it should be "application/pdf".

Comment: I was able to resolve this but changing Content Type to  'application/pdf' instead to '.pdf'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by changing Content Type to 'application/pdf' instead to '.pdf'  in the csv that i prepared to upload the attachments

[image]